# UITextField background behaviour change from iOS 4 to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

In my app I have a UITextField which is on top of a background image.  Under iOS 4 I had to set the backgroundColor property to 'clearColor' in order to make it look right.  Under iOS 4 the textfield looks like this...

[image]

This is how I want it to look.  Now, since upgrading to Xcode 4.3 (iOS 5) when I re-run the same project, the box looks like this...

[image]

Grrr. So under iOS 5 I changed the backgroundColor property to 'whiteColor' and it works fine.  However now, under iOS 4.x the box looks like this...

[image]

Note the ugly white corners!  So please, can anyone tell me what I should be doing here in order to get it to look normal under both iOS 4 and iOS 5 (i.e.  To look like the first image!).

Many thanks,
Simon

Comment: Did you rebuild with the updated SDK?

Comment: Just to know..have you try by import QuartzCore and by setting textField.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor; ?

Comment: No idea what's happening here - but it's now working.  I removed the line to set the backgroundColor property and it all seems fine in both 4 and 5.

Comment: im having the same issue but doing it through the xib, not sure what is going on either, pretty whack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem a few days ago. To solve this, I just set the borderStyle and comment the backgroundColor line. Everything just work fine, both iOS4 and iOS5.

```
//  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // just leave it, dont't set
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Comment: I've marked this correct as I'm fairly sure this is what fixed it for me too, but in all honesty can't be 100% as it's a bit of a vague issue.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me as well.  I made this single change and my issue was resolved, in all tests iOS 4.3 up through 5.1. (The issue in my project was exactly as described in the original post.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did to resolve this issue, you can check the version of iOS running on the device and do the handling accordingly, like this

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];
if(version < 5.0)
{
//user clear color
}else
{
//use white color
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might have to rebuild your project. Also, try and make this in a whole new project to see if it is actually a new change to Xcode, or if it is just that particular project to narrow things down. If you then isolate it to being something wrong with your particular project, try and "do it over" to see if it clicks then. But i see you solved it :=)